# Mongo DB problem - connections accumulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

I have a problem with the approach I use to connect to *Mondo DB*.

I use the following method:

```
import { Db, MongoClient } from "mongodb";

let cachedConnection: { client: MongoClient; db: Db } | null = null;

export async function connectToDatabase(mongoUri?: string, database?: string) {
  if (!mongoUri) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please define the MONGO_URI environment variable inside .env.local"
    );
  }

  if (!database) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please define the DATABASE environment variable inside .env.local"
    );
  }

  if (cachedConnection) return cachedConnection;

  cachedConnection = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }).then((client) => ({
    client,
    db: client.db(database),
  }));

  return cachedConnection!;
}
```

Everytime I need to connect to MongoDB I do as follows:

```
const { db } = await connectToDatabase(config.URI, config.USERS_DATABASE);
const myUniversity = await db
  .collection(config.MY_COLLECTION)
  .findOne({})
```

Everything seems ok, so *what is the problem*?

The problem is that the connections to my DB don't close after I use them. In fact I thought that my server is stateless so after every time i use my DB, the connections end. But it is not true! They stay alive, and after few hours of using my app mongo atlas sends me an email saying that the limit is exceeded.

As you can see in this screenshot, this chart is ever growing. That means that connections stay on and they accumulate. How do you think I can solve this problem?

[image]

Keep in mind that it uses `cachedConnection` only if I use the same connection. If I call a different API from the first one it creates another connection and it doesn't enter in `if (cachedConnection)` block, but it goes forward till the end.

Comment: A connection usually represents a pool of connections (aka connection pool). The connection pool has a default value of 10 for NodeJS  (varies depending upon the driver software). The API also has a `close` method - to close the connection. See the [MongoDB NodeJS Connection Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/#connection-guide).

Comment: Ok but I call that method with two parameters and it doesn't return me a a "client". You mean that I have to do `const { db, client } = await connectToDatabase(config.MY_URI, config.MY_DB);}`? and after each time I use it I have to do do `client.close()`? Doing so cached connections will not be available anymore, right?

Comment: `MongoClient.connect(mongoUri...` is what gives you the connection object (and the pool), so you use it to connect to the server from your NodeJS program from multiple applications / functions. It can be stored and re-used. Typically, you close it with your application. You don't need to `MongoClient.connect(mongoUri...` for every operation, query, etc., close it, and connect again.

Comment: Allright, but how can I do it in this case? How can I store it? I tried destructuring `client` but `client.close()` throws "Topology is closed, please reconnect"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple demo which will allow you to use the same connection throughout the application in different modules. There are three modules: the `index.js` is the starter program, the `dbaccess.js` is where you have code to create and maintain a connection which can be used again and again, and a `apis.js` module where you use the database connection to retrieve data.

**index.js:**

```
const express = require('express');

const mongo = require('./dbaccess');
const apis = require('./apis');

const app = express();

const init = async () => {
    await mongo.connect();
    app.listen(3000);
    apis(app, mongo);
};

init();
```

**dbaccess.js:**

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

class Mongo {
    constructor() {
        this.client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/", {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
    }

    async connect() {
        await this.client.connect();
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB server.');
        this.db = this.client.db('test');
        console.log('Database:', this.db.databaseName);
    }
}

module.exports = new Mongo();
```

**apis.js:**

```
module.exports = function(app, mongo) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        mongo.db.collection('users').find().limit(1).toArray(function(err, result) {
            res.send('Doc: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    });
}
```

Change the appropriate values in the url, database name and collection name before trying.

Comment: You can further refactor this database query code in the `apis.js` in a `dao.js` module.