# Mongodb in production sometimes generates an error : Cannot read property collection of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I created an app with Node.js and React. There is mongodb that React requests data from. For example, I have a collection of sweets in mongodb (using Atlas sandbox), and react component that displays a list of sweets. In development mode on localhost everything works perfectly with no issues at all. Once I upload it on my hosting account, about 2-3 times out of 10 I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined.
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is. Please help.

My request looks like this:

```
router.get("/sweets/all", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const db=req.app.locals.db
    if(db) {
        await db.collection("sweet").find().toArray((err,result)=> {
           if(err){
             res.status(200).send(err)
           }
           else{ res.status(200).send(result) }
        });
    } else{ res.status(400).send(["no db"]) }
} catch (err) {
   res.status(200).send(err.message);
}
});
```

ORiginally Mongodb Connection looked like that (no issues on localhost at all):

```
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const uri =
"mongodb+srv://*****:*****@cluster0.j7sne.mongodb.net/duesweets?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

let _db;

const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

client.connect((err, client) => {
if (err) {
  throw new Error();
}
_db = client.db("duesweets");
console.log("Connected to DB");
});

const getDb = () => {
return _db;
};

module.exports = {
getDb,
};
```

item-routes.js:

```
const {getDb}= require("./helpers/db-connection")

router.get("/sweets/all", async (req, res) => {
  try {
  const db=getDb()
     await db.collection("sweet").find().toArray((err,result)=>{
       if(err){
           console.log(err)
       }
       else{res.status(200).send(result)}
       
   });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send(err.message);
  }
});
```

Then I tried to use req.app.locals which also works on localhost:

```
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://****:****@cluster0.j7sne.mongodb.net/duesweets?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

MongoClient.connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true }).then((client) => {
  const db = client.db("duesweets");
  app.locals.db = db;
  console.log("Database connected");
});
```

Comment: The MongoDB connection part is a bit weird and seems like it was copy/paste from a route. Can you provide more code (like where `app` is defined and why there is a `res.send()`?

Comment: You can structure your code like as shown in this post an see it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68274240/mongo-db-problem-connections-accumulation/68295770#68295770

Comment: @JonathanMuller, I edited my question and added original mongodb connection code that I used. It always worked for me and I have another project with the same configuration and it never has issues. The problem is that in this particluar project localhost works fine, but on hosting it sometimes works and sometimes an error. Res.send I used to pass an error if any to the front end React side, to display an error

Comment: @Sobolishche your `client.connect` if slow will take a lot of time to set the internal variable `_db`.
locally it works ok because it connects really fast on startup, before you can do any request.

your hosting probably don't keep your app alive and spawn it when a request arrives, making the request fail as the app don't have enough time to connect to the DB.

you can replace your getter by a promise that do the connection and resolve with DB, and then use this promise to get your DB anywhere in your code (by awaiting).

it should solve your issue